# Can we use time change based on timezone in Codeigniter Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

```
// Timestamp to parse
let s = 'Thu Oct 01 2020 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';

// POJS
console.log(new Date(s).toString());

// With moment.js
let format = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ';
console.log(moment(s, format).format(format));
```

HI,

Can we use this in PHP Codeigniter Controller? or any other way to change time based on system timezone ?

Thanks.

Comment: yes of course, as long as you provide the necessary format, not codeigniter exclusive, php will understand that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: but how to get system timezone?